# Does a linear transformation change the family of distribution of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given a random variable $X$, I am wondering if the linear transformation $Y = aX+b, a,b \in \mathbb{R},$ will be (up to scale change and shift) of the same family of distributions, i.e. if X is Poisson/Gamma/normal...., then Y will also be Poisson/Gamma/normal... respectively. I know that this holds for the normal and exponential distribution, but I am not sure if it holds for any distribution no matter if discrete or continuous. Thanks.

Comment: 'family of distributions' is vague. We say that distributions of $X$ and $aX+b$ are of the same 'type'. See 'convergence of types' in Billingsley's book.

Comment: Can you give an example of a distribution such that the linear transformation will lead to a distribution (CDF or density or pmf) that is not of the same type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[upgrading this to an answer from the comments.]

It is true that your new CDF will be be a scaled and shifted (and possibly reflected) version of your original CDF, provided either $a>0$, or $a<0$ and the variable is continuously distributed,
since for $a>0$, $$P(aX+b\leq x)=P(X\leq \frac{x-b}{a}),$$
and for $a<0$ and $X$ continuously distributed,
$$P(aX+b\leq x)=P(X\geq \frac{x-b}{a})=1-P(X< \frac{x-b}{a})=1-P(X\leq \frac{x-b}{a}).$$

Likewise in either of these cases if the distribution is absolutely continuous, we obtain a similar result for the density by differentiating.

Whether or not that means it is in the same family depends on the family.

For example, if $X$ is Poisson, then $X$ is always a non-negative integer, and all of these have positive probability, but the random variable $aX+b$ will never have both of those properties unless $a=1$ and $b=0$.

[Update: As you have pointed out in the comments, exponential distributions also do not remain exponential under a linear change of variables unless $b=0$.]

Comment: But this will then mean that $Y = aX+b, X \sim $ Poisson ($\lambda$), will not be a distribution  altogether ? And not only this one.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following the question.  $X$ and $Y$ are random variables.  They are not distributions themselves, though they certainly ***have*** distributions.  In my example $X$ is Poisson, but $Y$ is not.  But both $X$ and $Y$ certainly have distributions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just a misunderstanding.

Comment: Is there a necessary or sufficient condition for the distribution of $X,$ so that the distribution of $aX+b$ will be of same type ? I also realized that the exponential distribution will fail to remain of same type under this transformation. Is this correct ?

Comment: @user996159 I only became familiar with types just now after looking at geetha290krm's comment, but looking at Billingsley it seems like by definition, the distribution of $aX+b$ is of the same type as $X$, provided $a>0$.

Comment: @user996159 it's true under a linear change exponentially distributed r.v.'s may fail to be exponentially distributed.  However, that doesn't mean they are different "type". "Type" as defined in Billingsley is always preserved under a linear change of variables with $a>0$.

Comment: Now I am fully confused. How about your conclusion above that $aX+b$ will not be Poisson if X is Poisson for $a>0$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148990/discussion-between-m-w-and-user996159).